# ListBox.Contains does not work as expected

Tags: c#, listbox

i have 2 errors in my code and can not figure out how to solve this.

This is my code:

```
    private void add_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`
    {
        try
        {

            if (list_selected.Contains(List_selection.SelectedItem))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't add the same type twice");
            }
            else
            {
                list_selected.Items.Add(List_selection.SelectedItem);
            }
        }
        catch 
        {

            {
                MessageBox.Show("No type selected");
            }

        }
    }
```

These are the errors:

Error   1

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Contains(System.Windows.Forms.Control)'
>   has some invalid arguments

Error   2

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control'    C:\Projects\flashloader2013\mainapplication\Form1.cs    467 44  Main

Please help me. ]

`List_selection` and `list_selected` are `ListBoxes`.

Comment: Which lines are highlighted when you double click the error?

Comment: @OP: Please don't add `CLOSED` to the question's title if you have accepted an answer. [**Closed**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question) has a special meaning on SO.  The title is also the most important part of a question. It should only contain the subject of the question. It is used for search engines so that other people can find answers to similar questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write:

```
if (list_selected.Items.Contains(List_selection.SelectedItem))
```

Otherwise you check the controls collection of the listView/Listbox (whatever control that could contain other controls)

Comment: Sorry, missmatched the Controls ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of [`ListBox.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.contains.aspx) which checks if a control contains a child-control you want to check if the ListBox contains this item. So use [`ListBox.Items.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.contains.aspx):

```
if (list_selected.Items.Contains(List_selection.SelectedItem))
```

Answer (score 2):

Turn this:

```
if (list_selected.Contains(List_selection.SelectedItem))
```

into:

```
if (list_selected.Items.Contains(List_selection.SelectedItem))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   if (listBox1.Items.Contains(listBox1.SelectedItem)) {
        MessageBox.Show("Can't add the same type twice");
   }
   else {
        listBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not work because you are trying to query the ListBox.

If you see your add

```
list_selected.Items.Add(List_selection.SelectedItem);
```

you will see that you have to query the Items. like below.

```
list_selected.Items.Contains(List_selection.SelectedItem))
```